# How to pass value in url without variable with php?

Tags: php, url

I need to pass a value in the URL without any variable or parameter.
For example, this is my existing URL:

```
http://www.example.com/stores?shop=TestShop
```

I want to convert this into:

```
http://www.example.com/TestShop
```

IS there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use htaccess to do url rewriting. This means that your server will interpret `http://www.example.com/TestShop` as `http://www.example.com/stores?shop=TestShop`. You're going to want to look into url rewriting with htaccess using regular expressions. You can start your research here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/#introducing-regular-expressions